# Case insensitive sort not working (.NET Core, EF)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, entity-framework-core

I want to sort a list of items which I retrieve from a Postgresql database in a case-insensitive way.

Assuming I have the following unsorted values: `A, B, a, c, b, C`

I want: `A, a, B, b, C, c`

But right now I get: `A, B, C, a, b, c`

Do I use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase wrong here?

Thanks for any help or hints!

```
public class SortingInfo
{
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }
    public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public Task<List<MyCustomType>> GetItemsAsync(SortingInfo sortingInfo)
{
    var items = _itemsRepo
        .Query
        .ApplySort(sortingInfo)
        .ToList();

    var mappedData = _mapper.Map<List<Entities.MyCustomType>, List<MyCustomType>>(items);

    return Task.FromResult(mappedData);
}
```

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, SortingInfo sortingInfo)
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    
    var objectProperty = propertyInfos.FirstOrDefault(p =>
        p.Name.Equals(sortingInfo.SortColumn.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (objectProperty == null)
    {
        return query;
    }

    var sortingOrder = sortingInfo.SortOrder == SortOrder.Asc
        ? "ascending"
        : "descending";

    return query.OrderBy($"{objectProperty.Name} {sortingOrder}");
}
```

Comment: What is the build SQL query? What database engine is this being ran on?

Comment: Are you sure it's not Automapper that changes the order? Did you check the order of `items`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason your items are ordered this way is due to your [current collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/collation.html).

You could either force a case-insensitive one or force the query to run and sort in code:

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<T> ApplySort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, SortingInfo sortingInfo)
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var objectProperty = propertyInfos.FirstOrDefault(p =>
            p.Name.Equals(sortingInfo.SortColumn.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (objectProperty == null)
        {
            return query;
        }

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(param, sortingInfo.SortColumn), param);     

        var materialisedQuery = query.ToList(); // this will force query execution!

        var orderByMethod = sortingInfo.SortOrder == SortOrder.Asc
            ? typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            : typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "OrderByDescending" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
        orderByMethod = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), objectProperty.PropertyType);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>>>(Expression.Call(orderByMethod, Expression.Constant(materialisedQuery), lambda)).Compile()();
}
```

Forcing a collation through EF would likely be painful (if possible at all - I'm not sure it allows you to do that).

There's an argument for sorting the final data sets in code vs in the database:

- on one hand you would have much easier time scaling your code out (RDBMS don't scale out well, and there's a limit on scale-up)
- but depending on your data you might find that supplying order helps SQL come up with much better execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to order by "upper"

Replace `objectProperty.Name` to `objectProperty.Name.ToUpper()` in `return query.OrderBy($"{objectProperty.Name} {sortingOrder}");`